# Let $S_n$ be the number of heads in the first n tosses of a fair coin, how does $S_n-n/2$ tend as $n$ approaches $\infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My book states:

> We shall see that Sn − n/2 tends to infinity as n tends to infinity. While
>   the difference will be small compared to n/2, it will not tend to 0. On the
>   other hand the difference Sn/n − 1/2 does tend to 0.

This is confusing  since by Chebychev's inequality, I thought $P(|S_n/n-1/2|\geq \epsilon) \space-> 0$ as $n\space ->\infty$ is equivalent to  $P(|S_n-n/2|\geq n\epsilon) \space -> 0$ as $n \space ->\infty$ so long as $\epsilon$ is varied with increasing $n$ such that $n\epsilon$ remains a constant, per the solution to a similar problem [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m20f10/public_html/HW7Solutions.pdf)(Section 8.1, problem 8)? Are the two problems here different?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: It does not tend to infinity, but its variance does (just calculate the variance).  Chebyshev says $$P[|S_n-n/2|\geq n\epsilon] \leq \frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}}{n\epsilon^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Actually $S_n-n/2$ does not tend to infinity
(nor does $|S_n-n/2|$). The situation is essentially a
symmetric random walk: more precisely as $n$ increases by $1$, then $S_n-n/2$
increases or decreases by $1/2$ with probability $1/2$ in each case. The symmetric
one-dimensional random walk is *recurrent*, with probability one, it takes the
value zero infinitely many times. But also $|S_n-n/2|$ is unbounded with probability one too.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $S_n = n\bar{X}_n$, hence given a fair coin you have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left( n\bar{X}_n - n/2 \right) = n \mathbb{E}\left( \bar{X}_n - 1/2 \right)=n(1/2 - 1/2) = 0,
$$
for all $n$, however

$$
\mathbb{V}\left( n\bar{X}_n - n/2 \right) = n^2 \mathbb{V}\left( \bar{X}_n - 1/2 \right)=n^2\frac{1}{4n}= n/4 \to \infty,
$$
hence, $S_n - n/2$ does not tend to $\infty$, i.e., it is a symmetric r.v. around $0$ with variance that tends to infinity.